# How cell editing works with extjs store manager?

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, store

I have this example code from **[Sencha's website](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing)**

```
Ext.onReady(function() 
{   
    Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        storeId:'simpsonsStore',
        fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
        data:{'items':[
            {"name":"Lisa", "email":"lisa@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-111-1224"},
            {"name":"Bart", "email":"bart@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1234"},
            {"name":"Homer", "email":"home@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1244"},
            {"name":"Marge", "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1254"}
        ]},
        proxy: {
            type: 'memory',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'items'
            }
        }
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        title: 'Simpsons',
        store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
        columns: [
            {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name', editor: 'textfield'},
            {header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex:1,
                editor: {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    allowBlank: false
                }
            },
            {header: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone'}
        ],
        selType: 'cellmodel',
        plugins: 
        [{ 
            ptype: 'cellediting',
            clicksToEdit: 1
        }],
        height: 200,
        width: 400,
        renderTo: 'grid'
    });

});
```

This `ptype: 'cellediting'` plugin allows for inline cell editing by just clicking on `textfield`.
I just cannot find any posts on **how and where the changed value gets saved?** How can I add a listener to a cell so that after each change I will be able to **`alert()`** the new value?

Thanks for any tips...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The record values are updated each time the editor is blurred (i.e. lose focus). Ext keeps track of fields in the records that have been modified, until you commit the changes (by syncing the store, for example).

To be notified that a field has been edited, use the [`edit`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-event-edit) event of the plugin. As you can see in the doc, you can install a listener for this event directly in the grid (no need to add the listener specifically to the plugin).

*Edit*

With your code, that would be something like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name', editor: 'textfield'},
        {header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex:1,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                allowBlank: false
            }
        },
        {header: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone'}
    ],
    selType: 'cellmodel',
    plugins: 
    [{ 
        ptype: 'cellediting',
        clicksToEdit: 1
    }],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: 'grid',

    listeners: {
        edit: function(editor, e) {
            var record = e.record;

            alert(Ext.String.format(
                'The field "{0}" or record #{1} has been changed from {2} to {3}', 
                e.field, record.get('id'), e.originalValue, e.newValue
            ));

            alert('The following fields of the records are dirty: ' + Ext.Object.getKeys(record.modified).join(', '));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thats perfect. But in case your store sync fails, how do you undo the above edit?? because although the record is unchanged, visually it stills display incorrect information?? I am talking specifically about a grid checkcolumn

Comment: That's another question, but you would use the failure callback of the sync method, and inside it you'd call [`reject`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-reject) on each record.

Comment: Thats exactly what i thought would undo it. And actually it does undo the record value, but on the grid it still shows the opposite (value set in beforeedit.)

Comment: You should post a question with a short reproductible example of the issue.